# contour integral complex conjugate

Tags: complex-integration

I'm having trouble trying to find this integral, where $C$ is the semicircle,
centre $z = 1$, of radius $1$, lying in the upper half-plane 
$$
\int_C \bar{z}\ {dz}
$$

Currently I have that,
$c(t)=1+e^{it}$, where $t$ is in $(0,\pi)$, and where $c$ is a parametrisation of the curve $C$.

So then I have that

$$
\int_C \bar{z}\ {dz}=\int_C (1+e^{-it})ie^{it}\ {dz}=\int_C (ie^{it}+i)\ {dz}=i\pi
$$

Is this correct? Probably not, but I can't see where im going wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated. Furthermore apologies for the bad notation.

Comment: $e^{-it}e^{it} \neq t$.

Comment: thanks, ivechanged it but the question still holds

Comment: Furthermore, $\int_0^\pi e^{it}\,dt$ (not $dz$!!)  equals $2i$.

Comment: Are you sure about the bounds on the integrals? When you change the integrand to being $t$-dependent, you also need to change the bounds and the $dz$.

Answer (score 1):

$\int\limits_C\bar{z}dz=\int\limits_0^{\pi}(1+e^{-it})ie^{it}dt=\int\limits_0^{\pi}ie^{it}dt+\int\limits_0^{\pi}idt=e^{i\pi}-1+i\pi=-2+i\pi.$